# Simple reading csv file tutorial code gives an error

Tags: fortran

CodeBlocks 17.12 for Fortran with GNU fortran compiler in Windows10

I am totally new to Fortran, and would like to read csv file with Fortran by the simple tutorial code below. However, it gives me an error: 'Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.' and I totally got lost.

The question might be too simple, but I really appreciate it if someone could give me an advice.

```
    program readSimpleCSV
      implicit none
      integer, parameter :: n = 5
      real x, y, z
      integer i
      open (17, file='book1.csv', status='old')
      read (17, '()')      ! skipping the header
      do i = 1, n
        read (17, *) x, y, z
        print *, x, y, z
      end do
      close (17)
    end program readSimpleCSV
```

The csv file: 'book1.csv' is as below

```
    X,Y,Z
    1.2,3.4,5.0
    2.2,3.3,6.2
    0.3,2.1,5.98
    4.2,3.6,1.25
    5.03,2.3,3.44
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Are you sure you are running exactly this code? Try to enable all compiler checks like `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`,,rerun the code and report the complete output.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for your comment. I could not find -fbacktrace in my codeblocks, but added other options. It returned the error as following.               'Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  ffffffff'

Comment: Looks like your compiler instalation is broken or  does not.create correct exexutables for your Windows.

Comment: @Vladimir hmm, I see. Another simple code like adding numbers in do-loop works, but trying to read the file gives me the error. Anyway, thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Try to find out where it fails. Is it the open statement? Or the read statement? Try to add the `iostat=` specifier to both of them and try to check the resulting status. Check that the file is where the program is looking for it. The code is correct so the problem is somewhere in your toolchain or execution of the program.